# C# TabControl tabs disappearing after removing the end one

Tags: c#, tabs, overflow, hidden

Ok, So I have some tabs in a tab control. As soon as I have an overflow tab (when the tabs overflow onto another 'page' and the left/right arrows are shown) and I delete the end tab with `tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabControl1.SelectedIndex);`, where the selected index is that of the last tab, the overflow tab HEADER is still not shown but it's content is, as shown here:

[image]

How do i get my overflow tabs to show back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be a bug in the `TabControl`.

See this [MSDN page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/58a68582-27ed-4040-b598-99563e321e4b/tabcontrol-not-refreshing?forum=winforms) for a not so pretty solution!

Comment: Talk about a hard solution to a simple problem! seemed to work fine, though.